# Iteration in Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

We have a Linked List with 5 nodes

1 2 3 4 5

```
previous = pointing to 2
Head = pointing to 3
```

And if

```
prev.next=head.next;
head=head.next;
```

So i my question is if head is pointing to 3 and just deleted 3 by doing prev.next=head.next;
and the new linked list will be

```
1 2 4 5
```

and now i do head=head.next;
so how it will be going to 4 when i already delete the node with value 3 which was being pointed by head?

Comment: It is called `head` for a reason.  You should not be changing its value.  Use a different reference.  Call it `current` or something meaningful.  Otherwise, how are you going to find the beginning of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prev.next = head.next;` did not delete the node 3 from memory.

head is still pointing to 3, and head.next is still pointing to 4.

so writing `head = head.next` is fine, you just change the value head is pointing to.

Comment: So will it remain in the memory after head points to the next element or get removed after it ??

Comment: I believe after there are no more pointers to that object in memory - Java's garbage collector deletes it from memory.